# Remove first character from string in sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to Oracle and not sure how to remove the first character in the String.

For example this value

```
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Here I loop it and appending comma after each value. But unfortunately first time it is appending comma. Not sure how to remove it.

Comment: this is almost certainly a bad problem.  you should change how you are normalizing and not ever need to parse lists of numbers in a column

Answer (score 5):

you can use `SUBSTR` function

```
select substr(',1,2,3,4,5', 2) from dual
```

Answer (score 5):

One method is to use `ltrim()`:

```
select ltrim(<string>, ',')
```

I am suspicious whenever I see numbers like that in a string.  That is not a good way to represent lists of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can be a little more specific using a regexp that removes the first character only if it is a comma.

In oracle :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( 
    ',1,2,3,4,5',
    '^,',
    ''
) FROM DUAL;
```

Regexp explanation : ^ denotes the beginning of the string, followed by the comma. If the string matches, the matched part is replaced with the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Ltrim(<string>,'charecter')  
   ----to left trim charecters (left side of the string)
  ,Rtrim(<string>,'charecter')
       ---to right trim charecters (right side of the string)
```

For your query you require

```
       select Ltrim(<string>,',') from table
```